# get CPU and Memory usage on Linux with Flutter

Tags: linux, flutter, dart

I'm looking for some tips to retrieve cpu and memory usage in linux, using flutter framework. I tried **system_resources** and **linux_system_info** but no one seems working. I'm thinking to write in a file with a python script datas I need for but seems a bad solution, I hope exists something better.
Anyone can help me?
PS: Merry Christmas

Comment: Create a Flutter Linux plugin to get the CPU and memory usage in C++ and return the information to Dart

Comment: Can be an idea. I hope to get something just ready to use. Unfortunatelly i haven't many time to spend on this